# Is it possible to open a pbix file using Python and refresh it?

Tags: python, automation, powerbi, rpa

I want to develop an automation that will, after some steps, open a Power BI file and refresh the report.

I tried using **subprocess.Popen([path])**, but it didn't work. It appeared an error message, saying **[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**.

Is there any way to create such automation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

[Refresh a Power BI Dataset with Python](https://pbi-guy.com/2022/01/07/refresh-a-power-bi-dataset-with-python/)